# How to match the date in cell above, with a column of dates, and bring the value of cell left to the matched cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have dates arranged in a calendar format. Below every date row, there is a row to add notes. Now I have a separate task list in a column. I want to place those tasks automatically under the dates in the calendar. So basic logic I'm trying is if the date in the cell above matches with a date in the column specified, then copy the cell to the left of the matched value and bring it to the current cell.

Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wq9D1XQHN2_j40-0PcugYBV2Mmy1b9ZfDVCPUArcbCc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your question is not completely unclear. Please edit your question to show what formulas you have already tried? Please also supply an example of your current layout and an example of how a successful solution would appear. Also, please share your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for taking out time guys! I'm editing the question and placing the link to the sheet there. So basically you can see that Im trying to get this timeline sheet tasks to automatically populate in the calendar sheet in appropriate dates. Im not very good at google sheet formulas so I have manually linked the cells in the 2 sheets right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should be copied in cell E10 on "calendar View". Then copy the formula into each "Task" cell on Calendar View. The absolute cell references will ensure that the right values from "Timeline" are returned.

---

`=iferror(index(Timeline!$B$3:$C$13,match(E9,Timeline!$C$3:$C$13,0),1),"")`

Comment: Hi Tedinoz! Thanks for the help! I copied this formula in the first row in Calendar view which you can see in the same sheet link posted above and it works very well. But my only concern is that the dates which it doesnt match, formula shows error for those. What can we do for that?

Comment: @curiousfriend Oops. Sorry about that. Refer the updated answer. Now, if there is no match, a cell will take the value `""` and will appear as a blank cell. Of course, you could put some text in there, for example "no match" or whatever, and/or use conditional formatting according to the value of the cell.

Comment: Awesome!! You are a blessing. It has worked as I wished.